# Attach one window to another window in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, compiz, customization

In Ubuntu, is it possible to attach one window to another window (so that one window becomes the "parent window" of the other window)? I'd like to know if it's possible to do this for any two open windows (for example, a Firefox browser window and a gedit window).

Comment: what do you mean by *parent* ? do you expect that when closing the *parent* window the *child* window is closed too - or when moving the *parent* window the *child* window moves too ? I suggest you to specify that in your question

Comment: Yes, when closing the parent window, the child window is closed too.

Comment: I have no clue how to do what you are requesting. But I believe that the solution will be different for every *parent* applications. **I suggest you to edit your question and add in the title the name of your master application Firefox** that way your question will be more visible for the specialists of firefox.

Comment: I'd like to find out if it's possible to do this in an "application-agnostic" way, so I'd prefer to leave it as-is.

Comment: As a workaround, it is possible to nest one desktop session inside another desktop session in Ubuntu: http://superuser.com/questions/484181/create-a-draggable-desktop-inside-another-desktop-nested-desktops